# Distribution of a division of two absolutely continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Assume $Z,Y $ are independent standard normal random variables.

Find the distribution of $ Z/Y $.

The answer is that $ Z/Y $ is absolutely continuous random variable with density

$$ f_{\frac{Z}{Y}}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi(1+x^2)} $$

Here's what I don't understand:

I tried to write:

\begin{align}
F_{\frac{Z}{Y}}(t) & =\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{Z}{Y}\leq t\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{Z}{Y}\leq t\cap Y<0\right)+\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{Z}{Y}\leq t\cap Y>0\right) \\[8pt]
& =\mathbb{P} (Z\geq tY\cap Y<0)+\mathbb{P}\left(Z\leq tY\cap Y>0\right) \\[8pt]
& =\mathbb{P}(Z\geq tY) \mathbb{P}(Y<0)+\mathbb{P}(Z\leq tY) \mathbb{P}(Y>0) \\[8pt]
& =\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P}(Z\geq tY)+\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{P} (Z\leq tY)
\end{align}

And then to calculate each term. for example :

$$ \mathbb{P}(Z\leq tY)=\mathbb{P} ((Z,Y)\in \{ (z,y):z\leq ty \} ) = \intop_{-\infty}^\infty \intop_{-\infty}^{ty} \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-\frac{z^2+y^2}{2}} \, dz\, dy $$

But this leads me to a wrong answer, and I'm pretty sure that the problem is somewhere in what I wrote before.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: The mistake is $P(Z \le tY \cap Y > 0) = P(Z \le tY) P(Y > 0)$; these are not independent events.

Comment: To find the distribution that you want first define $W:=(Y,Z)$, and then observe that $P[Z/Y\leqslant c]=P[W\in A_c]$ where $A_c:=\{\omega : Z(\omega )/Y(\omega )\leqslant c\}$

Comment: @Masacroso standard normal distribution, as mentioned.

Comment: @angryavian why not? it is given that $ Z $ and $ Y $ are independent

Comment: @FreeZe the events $\{Z\geqslant tY\}$ and $\{Y>0\}$ are not independent, both depends on $Y$

Comment: @FreeZe $Y$ appears in both events.

Comment: @Masacroso can you ellaborate on this observation you mentioned? I will calculate the integral myself ofcourse, but if you can just explain how can I get the right integral, it will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $W:=(Y,Z)$, then as $Y$ and $Z$ are independent $f_W=f_Y\cdot f_Z$, therefore for $A_c:=\{(s,t)\in \mathbb{R}^2 :s/t\leqslant c\}$ we have that

$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr [Z/Y\leqslant c]&=\Pr [W\in A_c]\\&=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_{A_c}(s,t)f_Y(s)f_Z(t)\mathop{}\!d(s,t)\\
&=\frac1{2\pi }\left(\int_{(0,\infty )}e^{-t^2/2}\int_{(-\infty ,tc]}e^{-s^2/2}\mathop{}\!d s \mathop{}\!d t+\int_{(-\infty ,0)}e^{-t^2/2}\int_{[tc,\infty )}e^{-s^2/2}\mathop{}\!d s \mathop{}\!d t\right)
\end{align*}
$$
Differentiating respect to $c$ gives
$$
f_{Z/Y}(c)=\frac1{2\pi}\left(\int_{(0,\infty )}te^{-\frac1{2}(1+c)^2t^2}\mathop{}\!d t-\int_{(-\infty ,0)}te^{-\frac1{2}(1+c)^2t^2}\mathop{}\!d t\right)\\
=\frac1{\pi }\int_{(0,\infty )}te^{-\frac1{2}(1+c)^2t^2}\mathop{}\!d t=\frac1{\pi(1+c^2)}
$$
∎

---

EDIT: alternatively, using the change to polar coordinates $(t,s)=(r\cos \alpha ,r\sin \alpha )$ we have that the condition $s/t\leqslant c$ is equivalent to $\tan \alpha \leqslant c \Rightarrow  -\pi/2<\alpha \leqslant \arctan c$, and as the tangent have two full periods on $(-\pi,\pi)$ then

$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\mathbf{1}_{A_c}(s,t)f_Y(s)f_Z(t)\mathop{}\!d(s,t)=\frac1{\pi }\int_{[0,\infty )\times (-\pi/2,\arctan c]}re^{-r^2/2}\mathop{}\!d (r,\alpha )
=\frac1{\pi}(\arctan c+\frac{\pi}{2})
$$

where the result follows again by differentiation.

Comment: How did you differentiate it with respect to $ c $ when $ c $ only appears in the bounderies of the integral?

Comment: @FreeZe it is just the fundamental theorem of calculus applied inside an integral. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) to see the general case

Answer (score 0):

Draw a picture of a $(y,z)$-plane and sketch the region consisting of points $(y,z)$ satisfying $z/y \le t$. This should look like two cones (or pizza slices) with points at the origin and extending infinitely away from the origin. Because the distribution of $(Y,Z)$ is rotationally symmetric, the probability that $(Y,Z)$ lies in this region is proportional to the total angle that these cones sweep out. The angle in question will involve arctangent and $t$, and differentiating to get the PDF will lead to the $\frac{1}{1+t^2}$ expression.

Comment: a priori I dont know that Z/Y is absolutely continuous, so why can we just differentiate the distribution? (Im sorry if this is trivial we just havent talked about diiferenitate the distribution to get the PDF in class yet)

Answer (score 0):

When you are separating two conditions (here: ${Y>0}$ and ${Y<0}$) you have to take it into account. For instance:

$ \Pr\{Z\leq tY \cap Y>0\} = \Pr\{Z\leq tY | Y>0\} \Pr\{Y>0\}$.

The condition effects the limits of integral that follows, i.e., where you have conditioned $Y$ to be positive, $y$ starts at $0$, not $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have concluded that $\Pr (Z\geq tY\cap Y>0) = \Pr(Z\geq tY) \Pr(Y>0).$

But these events are not independent, as may be seen by drawing a graph. Try it, for example, with $t=3.$ Look at the region of the $y,z$-plane where $y>0$ and $z>3y$ and the region where $y<0$ and $z>3y.$ These will get two very different probabilities.

You have $\Pr(Y>0) = 1/2,$ so $\Pr(Z\ge tY\mid  Y>0) = \dfrac{\Pr(Y\ge tY \cap Y>0)}{1/2}.$

This is $\displaystyle 2\int_0^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{ty} f(y,z)\,dz\,dy,$ where $f$ is the joint density.

**PS:** If you want to use polar coordinates here, notice that $\big[y>0 \text{ and } z>ty\big]$ amounts to $\big[ \arctan t < \theta < \pi/2 \big],$ and from there to the bottom line is a very short route.